# How to Delete a TFS 2017 Agent When The Build Server No Longer Exists

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

TFS 2017 Update 2 on premises

In the Default Agent Pool and Default Agent Queue I have a build agent listed that I want to get rid of. Everyone says to get rid of a build agent, you go to the build agent server itself and unconfigure the agent there. But the server that had that agent on it no longer exists, so I cannot do that. I've disabled the agent in TFS but I cannot find a way to just get rid if it from the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the agent by deleting it from the agent queues page. See the right delete icon. 
[image]Agent Queues page.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

So delete a queue, you right click on it and pick Delete. To delete an agent you click the X way at the right. Consistency? I kept right-clicking on the Agent, like I've done elsewhere in TFS.